# Nav mesh or colliders?

Tags: game-physics

I have some question about checking a moving in game when controller is joystick. 
For bots moving necessary using navigation system (navigation mesh or grid). But i dont sure what using for players moving: naviagation system (use raycast on nav mesh all time in game loop when player press button for moving) or physics system (check intersection with colliders in game loop)?

Comment: In RTS games Im sure for moving use navigation system but for me interesting a joystick (or keyboard).

Comment: There's lots of different approaches and no "one size fits all" solution. Often you may end up doing a combination of the two or maybe even something completely else

Comment: @UnholySheep Thank u for answer. I feeling that all approach can be usable but I think some one says "using nav system is wrong" or corresponding for physics system. If both approach usable i need implement both and after comparison.